# How do i get both file name & binary content col from .CSV files?

Tags: csv, powerquery

[image: Power Query]

I am trying to extract csv data to table by using below m code but unable to get file Name column while extracting.

M-code

```
  let    
    Source = Folder.Files(#"Folder Path"),
    #"CombinedBinaries" = Binary.Combine (Source [Content]),
    #"ImportedText" = Lines.FromText(Text.FromBinary(CombinedBinaries)),
    #"TableFromList" = Table.FromList(ImportedText, 
    Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("# 
    (tab)"), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
```

Are there any possibilities to get file name as well with CSV data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code to combine all CSV files in a directory that you can modify

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\temp"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Extension] = ".csv"),
#"Added CSVdata" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "CSVdata", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content])), type table),
#"Added Custom" =  Table.AddColumn(#"Added CSVdata", "Custom", each let name = [Name] in Table.AddColumn([CSVdata],"SourceFile", each name)),
#"Combined CSVdata" = Table.Combine(#"Added Custom"[Custom])
in #"Combined CSVdata"
```

or

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\temp"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".csv")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "CSV", each Table.PromoteHeaders(Csv.Document([Content]))),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom"[CSV], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "CSV", List,List)
in #"Expanded Data"
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing file name but now facing extracting issue of original csv data...there is no option to extract data properly into table. i have tried to split data by delimiter but its created one or two columns...
is it possible to add any delimiter (","/ ">") to split csv data column?
so, I can try to split data with available delimiter.

Comment: You should start a new question and share sample data with desired output for assistance